# Django demo won't run at all

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu

I'm a beginner with Django. I use it under Kubuntu 12.04LTS with Python 2.7(.3?).

I do: **$ django-admin.py startproject mysite**

Everything seems correct. Then I go to folder 'mysite' and I do:

**$ python manage.py runserver**

It should display a version information string and more...

In my case, I see nothing more than the bash prompt but I'm moved two levels lower in the folders.

Any hints? I don't know what to do neither where to start to look for a problem.

Comment: please, write your django version, file tree

Comment: Django 1.6 (I think, I'm away from the computer I tried Django on) and the file tree is like what is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ in "Creating a Project" section.

Comment: First, How did you download django 1.6? I just see django 1.5. Second. please show the basj prompt

Comment: It is possible that my Django is 1.5... As I said, I'm away from my computer where Django is. The bash prompt is ... nothing:

Comment: **$ python manage.py runserver** then a new prompt as if I pressed the ENTER key.

Comment: I dont know man, that is strange.